# Windows Phone Templates in VS2010 Professional

Tags: templates, windows-phone-7

I installed Windows Phone Developer Tools.
I can create the projects with Blend 4 or VS Express Edition.

I want to use the templates in Visual Studio 2010 Pro.
I can see the Windows Phone Game Template under XNA Studio but the other main templates are missing.
I can see them at this directory:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Silverlight for Windows Phone\1033
```

I reinstalled the Dev Tools many times but my VS2010 Pro can't load the templates!

Any solution?

Thanks,

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to reset the settings of VS with the command

```
devene.exe /InstallVSTemplates
```

or maybe

```
devene.exe /InstallVSTemplates /ResetSettings  ?
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241279.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The directory your looking at is for individual files the directory that you need to be looking for if you want to create new WP7 projects is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Silverlight for Windows Phone\1033
```

Comment: Yes. It does exist. But how can I load it  into VS2010PRO?

Answer (score 0):

If that file exists, you can access the templates by first selecting language, and then looking under the language for the template.  For instance, expand "Vishual C#", and you will see "Silverlight for Windows Phone as one of the template sets.

Comment: but id doesn't appear in that list in Visual Studio 2010 Pro. But it does in Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0):

You could have an earlier version of the phone tools already installed causing the template install to silently fail. Look for it on Add/Remove programs.

Otherwise it could be a corrupted VS install. Try to repair or uninstall/reinstall

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the developer setup should automatically install it for you. In case you are having issues, check this post... and let us know if it helped.

http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/04/29/windows-phone-developer-tools-ctp-refresh.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Three thoughts come to mind. Well, besides the obvious thought, how frustrating it must be.

A. Sometimes installs get messed up from various ctp installs/uninstalls in untested sequences. Feel free to try this that I wrote during WP7 CTP to try and help people resolve install issues. It helped some people deal with install issues. This may be a little overcatious, but doesn't take much longer. When it came time to install RTM I was able to do a single uninstall WPDT and install the tools, no hassles since.

[Known Good March -> April CTP Un/Install Sequence](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/85ba805e-6746-46e6-a2d2-4ed3ca3d725a)

B. Alternatively, if something is super messed up, try a clean install of Win7 on a spare hard disk. At least if it works you're more informed and can decide whether a clean OS or more tinkering is a better use of your time.

C. Do a BeyondCompare (or other directory comparison) to a friends install or an install on another PC, find what's different, copy the appropriate files over.

Answer (score -1):

it was a very long time ago ... but I got similar problem with Mango templates, under VS10 French version. Here the trick : 
http://blog.mathieu-perrein.net/post/SDK-WP7-Mango-aucun-template-sous-Visual-Studio-2010-en-francais.aspx