# WP7 Installed and Templates Not Available in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate installed. I installed all tools listed [here](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/getting_started).

When I create a new project in Visual Studio, I don't see anything about Windows Phone or XNA anywhere. I've tried reinstalling the tools. I've tried doing `devene.exe /InstallVSTemplates` following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900532/windows-phone-templates-in-vs2010-professional).

Am I missing something here?

**Update:** I did have VS2010 SP1 installed before I installed the WP7 developer tools.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you're seeing? I have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and all of the Windows Phone are in these locations: 

Visual C# -> Silverlight for Windows Phone

or

Visual C# -> XNA Game Studio 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this by doing the following:

1. Uninstall everything related to Visual Studio 2010
2. Install Visual Studio 2010
3. Install the WP7 developer tools
4. Install VS2010 SP1

What I found was, when installing the WP7 developer tools, if VS2010 SP1 is installed, the tools installer doesn't find VS2010 and the plugins/templates don't get installed.

If there is a way to fix this without doing a reinstall, I'd love to know.

Comment: sheesh, same problem here and i'm not really keen on reinstalling!

Answer (score 0):

Hi All,

I solve this problem as follows:

1. I'm creating a new project (silverlight for windows phone, for example) in Visual Studio Express.
2. Closing Express edition.
3. Open created project in my Ultimate edition! :)

Answer (score 0):

I did in this way:
goto the folder Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Silverlight for Windows Phone\
change the name folder 1033 to 2052
ran devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates

start visual studio 2010, I found those templates are available but  I got errors when try to create project form them .

So I changed the folder name back to 1033 and ran devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates again.